# error: ‘mbedtls_ssl_conf_tls13_key_exchange_modes’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, conan, tls1.3, mbedtls

When I compile my application with mbedtls using conan I get an error:

```
error: ‘mbedtls_ssl_conf_tls13_key_exchange_modes’ was not declared in this scope
```

my conan.py includes the latest version of mbedtls:

```
    requires = [...,  "mbedtls/3.2.1", ...  ]
```

when I use mbedtls as a git submodule I can configure it:

```
mbedtls/scripts/config.py set MBEDTLS_SSL_PROTO_TLS1_3
```

and my code does compile smoothly.
Does anyone know how to configure it so that I can compile it using conan?

Comment: It seems there is not enough information there, and it might require something that can be reproduce, with build files, some simple .cpp files, etc. I think it would be better to put together a small reproducible case and submit it to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues